# docker toolbox networking problems

Tags: networking, apache-spark, docker-machine, docker-toolbox, kitematic

Hi I want to have **multiple services communicate** with each other using **docker toolbox**: I would like to use https://github.com/gettyimages/docker-spark

In kitematic I can view the master's UI, however, the link to the slaves(s) do not work as docker cannot be natively installed on osx. 
This https://github.com/FoxtrotSystems/spark-cassandra-docker/blob/master/README.md does not fix the links between the services, even tough I am now able to (at least partially) view parts of the workers spark-ui.

Basically, the question boils down to:

Hoow can I (automatically) fix my `/etc/hosts` file on the mac to allow the services in `docker-toolbox` to talk to each other using their "real" names.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken at the [docker dns](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/configure-dns/) parameter?

Comment: I did not change the DNS settings so far. However in the master spark UI a link to the name `master`or an IP to the worker will not be resolved. So you would suggest `--link=CONTAINER_NAME` and manually link to IPs in the osx `\etc\hosts`?